# How to change color of the top part of screen

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android studio the latest version and Java
I'd like to know what this top part that's in black on my screen is called, is it the app bar or what is it called? I'd like to know how to change the color of it. That is the background color from black to something like blue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97h5b.jpg)

I've tried looking on YouTube videos but I haven't found anything

Comment: What UI framework are you using? Jetpack compose or XML layout?

Answer (score 0):

---

The top part is called the Action Bar. One solution for you is to make the change inside the onCreate method.:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Define ActionBar object
    ActionBar actionBar;
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // Define ColorDrawable object and parse color
    // using parseColor method
    // with color hash code as its parameter
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable
        = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0F9D58"));

    // Set BackgroundDrawable
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
}
```

}

There is also a way to change the color by modifying the colorPrimary item in your styles.xml. You can read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-color-of-action-bar-in-an-android-app/

---